# How to load js correctly in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a problem with my app on mobile device. When i refresh page on browser js not working first time but after i pan and zoom-out script will work.

Here is html file:

```
 <div class="userLogged" on-click="userMenu">
    <iron-icon icon="vaadin:user"></iron-icon>
 </div>
```

Here is my js:

```
userMenu(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var menu = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.userMenu');
    if (menu.classList.contains('slideRight'))
       menu.classList.remove('slideRight');
    else
    menu.classList.add('slideRight');
 }
```

Full code of my page

[image]
[image]

Comment: when your button doesn't respond on-click; can you see the icon `icon="vaadin:user"`

Comment: yes i can see my button.

Comment: Add your code as code instead photo. To able to make test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick sidenote: the name of your class should be `PageControl` as in `class PageControl extends Polymer.Element` -- should match the `id` of the dom-module.

I would make a property `userMenuClass` and do it like this:

```
<template>
    ...
    <div class="userLogged" on-click="userMenu"> ... </div>
    ...
    <div class$="[[userMenuClass]]"></div>  <!-- Note the $ after class. You need this to get binding to work properly. -->
...
</template>
<script>
    ....
    static get properties() {
        return {
            'userMenuClass': {
                type: String,
                value: () => 'userMenu slideRight'
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    userMenu (e) {
        let menuClass = 'userMenu';
        if (this.userMenuClass.indexOf('slideRight') == -1)  {
            menuClass += ' slideRight';
        }
        this.set('userMenuClass', menuClass);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is working good ty so much. Is it possible to get multiple values ?

Comment: I haven't tried it.  You could consider turning `userMenuClass` into a computed property, then making a second property after of `type: Array` like `arrayOfClasses`, and keeping the string values in there; then you could observe changes to that array, and any time a change were to occur, you could update `userMenuClass` with a `return arrayOfClasses.join(' ')` type thing. [Here's the Polymer docs on computed properties if you need them](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/observers#computed-properties)